# Equivalent code from C++ to Java for input validation

Tags: java, c++, code-translation

I've looked through and through and I haven't "found" an answer yet to this. I mostly use C++ but started some time ago a Java course in college and have been using it quite more. I was wondering whether there was an equivalent to something such as this in Java.

```
while (!(cin >> var))
{
   //do stuff
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(100, '\n');
}
```

This repeats the loop when someone types an invalid type into the variable e.g., a char or string into an int/double etc. And then it clears the flag and ignores 100 units until a newline. If it's a valid input, then it puts it into the variable.

So far all I've come up for Java is using something such as

```
while (!scanner.hasNextInt())
{
  //do stuff

  scanner.next();
}

var = scanner.nextInt();
```

When I've tried using this, sometimes the message would repeat twice depending on how many characters I wrote, and stuff like that. Is this the best way to do this type of input validation? I might be doing something wrong, but is this Java code supposed to behave exactly as in the C++ one or very similarly?

edit:

Tried again, and it seems like I was doing something wrong before, and the method I saw before works as intended.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int var1, var2;

        System.out.println("Enter int.");
        while(!scanner.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong input, enter integer.");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }


        var1 = scanner.nextInt();
        var2 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println(var1 + " " + var2);
    }
```

This is what I used. I needed to get two ints from the user, and I don't know what I was doing, but this seems to work.

Comment: _"And then it clears the flag and ignores 100 units until a newline."_ That's already wrong behavior in the c++ code anyways. So why would you want to transfer that wrong behavior to the java code?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm always open to suggestions and to ways of improving my code in any way possible. If you have any type of suggestions, throw them my way, I'll welcome any help I can get.

Comment: @BlazingMetalStorm `Equivalent code from C++ to Java for input validation`  Forget that C++ exists and just look for "Java code for input validation".  Trying to mimic, line-by-line, C++ code in Java is the wrong approach.  The same thing vice-versa.

Comment: You are mentioning a message in your questiona and also in the comment to @Zane's answer. You probably should also post the code, that produces this message.

Comment: I don't understand, why this gets close votes. The approach might not be the most reasonable one, but imho it is neither too broad, nor primarily opinion based.

Comment: @MikeMB The message I was getting was "Wrong input" showing twice, I can't remember what I did, but apparently I tried again and I can't replicate the error again, I must have done something wrong and did not notice. And like I said in my previous comment, if there's an actual way to do this much more efficiently and cleaner than this, then I'd welcome any knowledge I can get to improve myself.

Comment: I was talking about the code that literally produces the message, aka ` System.out.println("Wrong input, enter integer.");` which was previously missing

Answer (score 0):

The key is what delimiters Scanner is using. By default, \n isn't the only delimiter, generally any whitespace is a delimiter. Calling scanner.next() does not skip to the next time, it skips to the next "token." If you want to ignore the current line of input and skip to the next one, use scanner.nextLine()

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

"A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace."

Comment: I tried with nextLine() too but I can't remember why there was an error in the output. If I remember it was repeating the message of "Wrong input" like twice for some reason. I'll try again when I get home, and get back to you. Thank you for the suggestion.